# Dentry caches for deletion

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am developing a stateless filesystem to browse a network-based directory and files. I have my own inode cache of file/directory on my host machine.  I have designed my filesystem module in such a way that my host inode caches would be deleted when the evict_inode() function gets called from VFS layer. However, only in high memory pressure or writing 3 to /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches does this get flushed.  I am not sure how to flush my host inode caches.  Over time, my host side inode caches gets bigger and bigger as evict_inode() doesn't get called. This gets called when I write 3 to /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches.

I want to mark dentry caches and inode caches to be deleted in time-bound fashion as NFS does, but I am not sure how to achieve this.

Or, any better idea to achieve this?  It would be helpful to have the VFS inode sync with my host inode.  Any idea would be well appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To free pagecache: 
echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

To free dentries and inodes:
echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

To free pagecache, dentries and inodes:
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

Read more: http://linuxpoison.blogspot.jp/2010/08/how-to-free-linux-kernel-page-cache.html#ixzz24ni162iL

quoted from : http://linuxpoison.blogspot.jp/2010/08/how-to-free-linux-kernel-page-cache.html

Answer (score 0):

> I want to mark dentry caches and inode caches to be deleted in time-bound fashion as NFS does, but I am not sure how to achieve this.

I don't think NFS caches inodes and dentry get "deleted" after expiry. The stale inodes and dentry are just revalidated if expired. To actually evict them from cache, I think simplest idea is to garbage collect the stale entries. (One simple way to do that would be to put `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` in a cron job...) FUSE too has time bound validation.